# How can i do a multiple request with asynchronous task, for know when i finished all request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, ionic2, httprequest

Hello my dear programmer companions, I want to do a multiple http request using promises for know when to http request finish, i have this code, but doesn't work, and I go here for your help.

This is my code:

```
    promisesMappingIp(){
  var promises = [];
  for(var i = 1; i < 255; i++){
    promises.push(this.http.get(`http://192.168.1.`+i+`/hello`).map((res:Response) => {
            try{
              return res.json();
            }catch(err){
              return {};
            }
          }));
  }

  Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
    promises.forEach((x) =>{
      x.subscribe(data => {

      });
    });
  }).catch((err) =>{
    console.error(err);
  });
}
```

And in my console throws me that error:

ERROR Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Object, type: 3, url: null }

I'm using Ionic 2 for a school project and I really need your help, I want to map all the ip's that return me a response = "greetings!".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem using XMLhttprequest, this is my code, i hope that this helps anyone with the same issue:

```
    getService(ip: string, param: string): Promise<any> {
     let url: string = `http://${ip}/${param}`;
     return new Promise((r,j) =>{
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open("GET", url, true);
     xhr.onload = function(e){
       if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
         r(ip);
       }
     }
     xhr.onerror = function(err){
       r(null);
     }
     xhr.send(null);
   });
 }
```

And this is the methor i use for call:

```
  getIpList(){
  let promises = [];
  for(var i = 1; i < 255; i++){
  promises.push(this.nodeProvider.getService(`192.168.1.${i}`, 'hello'));
  }
  Promise.all(promises).then((arrayIp) => {
   let clean = arrayIp.filter(ip => !!ip);
  });
}
```

I hope I have been able to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

you can send multiple http requests using `Observable`

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

promisesMappingIp() {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 255; i++) {

        promises.push(this.http.get(`http://192.168.1.` + i + `/hello`));
    }

    Observable.forkJoin(promises)
        .subscribe((response) => {
            console.log(response[0]);
            console.log(response[1]);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) has a fast fail. This means that it will fail as soon as the first promise fails.

You need to intercept the failure and do not propagate it, with something like this:

```
promises.push(this.http.get(`http://192.168.1.`+i+`/hello`).map((res:Response) => {
            try{
              return res.json();
            }catch(err){
              return {};
            }
          }).catch(err=> ({ error: err })));
```